# How do i open a new window on the click of a button with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a text base game and would like to get a new root window on the click of a button while simultaneously closing the original one?

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can offer relevant advice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Packages
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, BOTTOM
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

#Create Window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("360x740")
root.resizable(True, True)
root.title("Box")
root.configure(bg="black")

#Load Image
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=360, height=360, bg="black")
tk.Canvas(bg="black")
canvas.pack()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("sample_image.jpg"))
canvas.create_image(180, 200, image=img)

#Create Text Widget
T = tk.Text(root, height=10, width=52, bg="black", fg="white")
l = tk.Label(root, text="Hard Living by Amsha", fg="white", bg="black")
l.config(font=(None, 14,))
story = """
"""
l.pack()
T.pack()

#Continue Button
yes_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Continue", command=lambda: next_window())
yes_button.pack(pady=75, side=BOTTOM)

T.insert(tk.END, story)

root.mainloop()

def next_window():
    root.quit()
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("360x740")
    root.resizable(True, True)
    root.title("Hard Living")
    root.configure(bg="black")

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you mean to actually answer your own question? This seems like you meant to add this to your question......`next_window()` will throw an error so this has to be accidental.

Comment: this is my first post on stack overflow and i cant for the life of me figure how to close a window and open a new window. sorry if i did this wrong.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).